# NoClassDefFoundError when using AWS SDK for Java

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, amazon-athena

I am trying to use the AWS Athena library in my Java application.
Although the dependency works fine in compile time, it fails in runtime with `NoClassDefFoundError`. I made sure the dependency is in the classpath at runtime.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>athena</artifactId>
   <version>2.16.75</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace and your pom.xml?